# Efficiently formatting every item in a Python list

Tags: python, csv

I am processing a CSV file. My code reads the file and returns a list for every row, where each element in the list represents a different field. At the moment there are 67 elements in each list and there could be thousands of rows.

This is the code the reads and processes the CSV:

```
def parse_quoted_csv(file_contents):
    """Parse a CSV file where each element is double-quoted"""

    # split the file into separate lines
    lines = file_contents.splitlines()

    # create a csv reader
    reader = csv.reader(
        lines,
        quotechar='"',
        delimiter=",",
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
        skipinitialspace=True,
    )

    # reader is an iterator, skip the first line
    next(reader, None)

    # yield the results
    for line in reader:
        yield line
```

Here's an example of what one might look like:

```
['U1234567', 'Individual', '', 'USD', 'STK', 'MSFT', 'MICROSOFT, CORP', '272093', 'US5949181045', 'ISIN', '594918104', 'US5949181045', 'NASDAQ', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2364593439', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '20220411;094043', '20220411;094043', '20220411', '20220413', '20220411', '', 'BUY', '10', '289.29', '2892.9', '-2892.9', '-1', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'USD', '0', '', 'LMT', 'ORDER', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '', '0.0', '0.0 ()']
```

I need to iterate through every item in the list. Each item will be checked and some will be formatted from a string to a `datetime` object or `Decimal` type.

(I'm doing this to insert the record into my DynamoDB table.)

For example, I would apply the following to the element at index 35 `20220411;094043`:

```
dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d;%H%M%S')
```

What is the most efficient way to apply formatting to every element in the list?

Note: I don't have access to pandas. I'm only using methods from the Python standard library.

Comment: You could use Pandas and read your CSV file into a data frame whose columns have their own defined types..

Comment: Why do you not have access to Pandas.... This is reinventing the wheel

Comment: You're doing it in a loop, right?  It's just `row[35] = datetime.strptime(row[35], '%Y%m%d;%H%M%S')`.  There's really no efficiency aspect to it.

Comment: @BeRT2me this is not my code and I working within the environment I have access to

Comment: Where does this list come from? Can you build it originally as some other data structure that is more appropriate for the data? If for example, you put this in a class with named fields, you can more quickly format only the date fields.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added to the question

Comment: @JasonStrimpel If the first row of the csv file contains headers, you can use `csv.DictReader`. This gives you a dict for each row so you can easily access the date values without iterating over the entire row.

Comment: OP, did you find a satisfactory solution for this?

Comment: A solution, yes, but nothing that answered my question. I was able to pass the list of lists downstream and process it using Pandas. Not what I wanted but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about efficiency; concern yourself with getting this done *right*.

Use Python's try/except blocks, incrementally trying to convert each string value to some other known type.

```py
try:
  new_val = some_conversion(str_val)
  output.append(new_val)
  continue
except TheExpectedExceptionForAnExpectedFailedConversion:
  pass
```

Specify the expected Exception if the particular conversion fails, and then `pass` it.  I recommend *against* doing a "bare except":

```py
try:
  new_val = some_conversion(str_val)
  output.append(new_val)
  continue
except:  # potentially bad, will hide legitimate exceptions
  pass
```

as that will bury a potentially meaningful problem you'll want to know about and fix.

This will involve a little trial and error, so maybe start with a smaller sample of your data?

(that very practice helped me dial in the exception for the Decimal class as I was writing this )

The order of the conversions matters: for example, if you want to keep ints and Decimals separate (distinct), you'll want to try and convert to int before you try convert to Decimal, because `Decimal()` can successfully convert an integer number, but `int()` cannot successfully convert a floating point (decimal) number.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime as dt
import decimal
import pprint

input_rows = [['U1234567', 'Individual', '', 'USD', 'STK', 'MSFT', 'MICROSOFT, CORP', '272093', 'US5949181045', 'ISIN', '594918104', 'US5949181045', 'NASDAQ', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2364593439', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '20220411;094043', '20220411;094043', '20220411', '20220413', '20220411', '', 'BUY', '10', '289.29', '2892.9', '-2892.9', '-1', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'USD', '0', '', 'LMT', 'ORDER', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '', '0.0', '0.0 ()']]

output_rows = []
for input_row in input_rows:

    output_row = []
    for str_val in input_row:

        # value = value.strip()  # if you want to normalize the strings first
        if str_val == "":
            output_row.append(None) # or "", whatever makes sense for you
            continue

        try:
            dt_val = dt.datetime.strptime(str_val, "%Y%m%d;%H%M%S")
            output_row.append(dt_val)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass

        try:
            int_val = int(str_val)
            output_row.append(int_val)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass

        try:
            decimal_val = decimal.Decimal(str_val)
            output_row.append(decimal_val)
            continue
        except decimal.InvalidOperation:
            pass

        # try:
        #     ...

        # Finally, just accept str_val as string
        output_row.append(str_val)

    output_rows.append(output_row)

pprint.pprint(output_rows)
```

When I run that against your input, I get:

```py
[[
  'U1234567',
  'Individual',
  None,
  'USD',
  'STK',
  'MSFT',
  'MICROSOFT, CORP',
  272093,
  'US5949181045',
  'ISIN',
  594918104,
  'US5949181045',
  'NASDAQ',
  None,
  ...
  None,
  datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 11, 9, 40, 43),
  datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 11, 9, 40, 43),
  20220411,
  ...
  Decimal('289.29'),
  Decimal('2892.9'),
  Decimal('-2892.9'),
]]
```